# Are Honorary Degrees Awarded to Those Lacking PhDs?

Tags: phd, degree

Have honorary degrees ever been conferred on someone lacking a PhD?

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/are-honorary-degrees-awarded-to-those-lacking-phds?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

all the time. Honorary degrees have been awarded to popstars, athletes, etc. 
See for example [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorary_degree)

Comment: does anyone know of a longer/more complete list of recipients than those mentioned on wikipedia?